# String concatenation without + (just space or adjacent strings) in Python 2.7.5?

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why this isn't just a syntax error?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
$ python
>>> 'a' + 'b'                # string concatenation, as expected
'ab'
>>> 'a' 'b'                  # still string concatenation ?
'ab'
>>> "a"'b'                   # or even this ...
'ab'
>>> ""''""''""''""''""''""   # or this !?
''
```

I've googled and searched the python docs but 
haven't found anything related. Just a bug?

Comment: This is a language design mistake from the early days of Python. [Guido wanted it gone](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-May/020527.html) not too long ago; I'm not sure what the current opinions among the core developers are, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it removed if there's ever a Python 4.

Answer (score 3):

Adjacent string literals are combined into one at the parsing stage.  This is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).